# What are the mandatory options for loading Excel file?

Tags: excel, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-excel

I have loaded an excel file from S3 using the below syntax, but I am wondering about the options that need to be set here.

Why is it mandatory to set all the below options for loading excel file? None of these options are mandatory for loading other file types like csv,del,json,avro etc.

```
val data = sqlContext.read.
format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").
option("location", s3path).
option("useHeader", "true").
option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true").
option("inferSchema","true").
option("addColorColumns", "true").
load(path)
```

I get the below error if any of the above options(except location) are not set:

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("location", s3path).load(s3path)
```

Error message :

```
Name: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message: Parameter "useHeader" is missing in options.
StackTrace:   at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.checkParameter(DefaultSource.scala:37)
          at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:19)
          at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:7)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:345)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:132)
          at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:47)
          at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:47)
          at time(<console>:36)
```

Comment: Need I remind you to accept the answers for your other questions ? Please review your old questions and accept the answers that solved your problem to close the issue !

Comment: I have already left you many comment on those questions !

Comment: Thanks @elisah I will do it today

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the options for `spark-excel` are mandatory except for `userSchema` and `sheetName`.

You can always check for that in the DataSource source code that you can find [here](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/crealytics/spark/excel/DefaultSource.scala).

You have to remember that this data source or data connector packages are implemented outside of the spark project and each comes with his rules and parameters.